# Sharing /tmp between two containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using `docker-compose` to spawn two containers. I would like to share the `/tmp` directory between these two containers (but not with the host `/tmp` if possible). This is because I'm uploading some files through `flask` to `/tmp` and want to process these files from `celery`.

```
flask:
    build: .
    command: "gulp"
    ports:
        - '3000:3000'
        - '5000:5000'
    links:
        - celery    
        - redis
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app:rw

celery:
    build: .
    command: "celery -A web.tasks worker --autoreload --loglevel=info"
    environment:
        - C_FORCE_ROOT="true"
    links:
        - redis
        - neo4j
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app:ro
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can used a named volume:

```
flask:
    build: .
    command: "gulp"
    ports:
        - '3000:3000'
        - '5000:5000'
    links:
        - celery    
        - redis
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app:rw
        - tmp:/tmp

celery:
    build: .
    command: "celery -A web.tasks worker --autoreload --loglevel=info"
    environment:
        - C_FORCE_ROOT="true"
    links:
        - redis
        - neo4j
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app:ro
        - tmp:/tmp
```

When compose creates the volume for the first container, it will be initialized with the contents of /tmp from the image. And after that, it will be persistent until deleted with `docker-compose down -v`.

Comment: Will host have access to this volume?

Comment: Indirectly. The host has access to anything it wants with a container, just like it does with any running process outside of a container. I don't recommend directly accessing named volumes on the filesystem, but instead use a container to mount it and access the contents in case docker moves the volume directory structure in the future. If you need direct access from the host, use a host volume, but you'll lose the initial copy from the image.