# Sharing /tmp folder between host and container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am currently working on transforming my single application with multiple services into multiple docker containers running each of those. My current problem is the following: These services originally share some files located on the tmp/ folder so the host's tmp/ folder would need to be mounted and shared among the containers.

I already tried the most obvious solution which is mounting the folders like what normally would be done:
This indeed does share the folders as intended but has the effect of deleting all the contents of the containers' tmp/ folders which breaks the application.

```
services:
  first:
    image: first_image
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: first/Dockerfile
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"

    volumes:
    - ./tmp/:/tmp
```

Is there any way to properly do what I am trying to do? Or at least is there a way to mount the files before my service inside the container starts? This way the temp files would be created after and not be deleted.This thread was the closest I found to solve my problem but it didn't address the files being deleted
[Sharing /tmp between two containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471631/sharing-tmp-between-two-containers)

Comment: Relying on a populated tmp folder to have a functionnal service when launching a container from an image sounds very dangerous. As a simple example, a lot of tools / distributions / base images very often integrate a tmp dump on occasions. Your app should create the tmp files at container startup. In such case, bind mounting the host tmp in the container should work (although I would not do it mainly for potential security reasons).

Comment: I can see your point, actually it seems a bit odd to have a shared system folder like this when my main goal is to try to decouple the application. I also looked into bind mounting it but according to the docker docs binding into a non-empty folder would obscure (whatever that means) the container files and most of the time would result in a broken container. Link to it: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: Your app should not break and rely on a populated tmp folder with specific files.  It should not be a problem to clear it out on startup.